# find image with image name in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, command

I am working on an iOS project. How can I navigate `"somepicure.png"` quickly when I find
`[UIImage imageNamed:@"somepicture.png"]`?

I have tried right click and click with control/option/command, but none of them works.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "navigate"? or do you mean navigate to?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 Yes, navigate to. Sorry for poor English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the cursor is clicked on "somepicure.png", do shift+command+O. This is quick open and it will populate the search field with the word you are clicked on and show you location

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean when you see a piece of code refer to a file in your application bundle, you want to be able to go from the piece of code to the file like you do when you use a feature like "Jump to definition"?  As far as I am aware, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the KSImageNamed plugin. I use it and it works very well. It autocompletes all image names in  your project.

http://github.com/ksuther/KSImageNamed-Xcode